# Package transparent, tcolorbox and tikz incompability

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, transparency

I had a problem with transparency, it wasn't show in pdf output. 
I have a similar problem with some tikz picture, that were not visualized well.
I noticed that the problem with this two package (tcolorbox and tikz) was due to another package, I removed it and now the pdf works fine.
The package was, weirdly, the "transparent" package.
Can someone explain what was going on?
I also have an other question, there's a difference from the package pgf and pgfplots? And from tikz to pgf?

Comment: Before you start ranting, you might want to explain what you are doing, where does this transparency come from, is it LaTeX generated, from a PNG.... As always on this site we like minimal examples.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.